# OpenLayers 3 - retina vs cached tiles

Tags: caching, openlayers-3, geoserver, retina

I have an application which serves some layers from GeoServer (GeoWebcache) tile cache. By default it stores them in 256*256 pixel resolution but the ol.source.TileWMS source requests 512*512 pixel ones when using a retina Macbook Pro which causes the server to reply:

> 400: The requested tile dimensions 512x512 do not match those of the
>   grid set (256x256)

(It perfectly works on my Lenovo T420.) Is there a way to force it to use 256*256 tiles on the rMBP too?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Balázs Eigner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it looks like it's really easy to solve: you have only have to set 'hidpi' option to false on the source.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. Do you maybe have an explanation for this?

Answer (score -1):

```
var layers = [ new ol.layer.Tile({
        source : new ol.source.TileWMS({
            hidpi : false,
            url : tiledArcGISMapServer,
            params : {
                'LAYERS' : 'guangdong_level16',
                'TILED' : true,
                'SRS' : 'EPSG:900913',
                'FORMAT' : 'image/jpeg'
            },
            tileGrid : gr,
            serverType : 'geoserver'
        })
    }) /* , layer */];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and for posting your first answer. To make the answer better, please consider formatting the code (use {}) and adding some explanation as to why the answer is correct. See [answer] for help.